Springboot graphql controller with Webflux
I have a graphql controller in a reactive application using Webflux.
The graphql controller is working fine, but I need to add standard cursor pagination as indicated here:
https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#slicing
After reading spring graphql 1.2.6 documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/controllers.html#controllers.schema-mapping.subrange
I updated my springboot version to 3.2.4, and I worked my way through the necessary modifications.
I modified my root query from:
users(count: Int, offset: Int, companyId: ID): [User]!

to:
users(first:Int, after:String, last:Int, before:String, companyId: ID): UserConnection

Then I modified my controller to:
@QueryMapping
public Mono<Window<User>> users(@Argument UUID companyId,
                               ScrollSubrange subRange,
                               @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
    return userService.getUsers(principal, companyId, subRange, Sort.by("username"));
}

Here my service (forget the companyId filter for now):
public Mono<Window<User>> getUsers(@NotNull Principal principal, UUID companyId, ScrollSubrange subRange, Sort sort) {
    ScrollPosition position =  subRange.position().orElse(ScrollPosition.offset());
    Limit limit= Limit.of(subRange.count().orElse(100));
    Objects.requireNonNull(principal);
    return visibilityService.findVisibleUsers(principal, User.class)
        .collectList()
        .flatMap(list -> userRepository.findByIdIn(list, position, limit, Sort.by("username")));
       

}

and my repository:
Mono<Window<User>> findByIdIn(Collection<UUID> uuid, ScrollPosition position, Limit limit, Sort sort);

Now: I see with the debugger that when I execute the query
{
  users(first: 1) {
    edges {
      node {
        username
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}

the controller receives correctly the subrange, and the repo is called with the right parameters. But then an exception occurs in
org.springframework.graphql.data.pagination.ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor.ConnectionDataFetcher#adaptDataContainer
and I get:
    2024-04-11 09:00:43,882 [reactor-http-kqueue-2] DEBUG  n.g.e.Execution - Executing 'df6d383b-2' query operation: 'QUERY' using 'graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy' execution strategy 
2024-04-11 09:02:56,796 [reactor-tcp-kqueue-1] ERROR  o.s.g.e.ExceptionResolversExceptionHandler - Unresolved IllegalStateException for executionId df6d383b-2 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConnectionAdapter for: com.tierra.suite.userservice.model.entity.user.User
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.pagination.ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor$ConnectionDataFetcher.adaptDataContainer(ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor.java:237)
    at org.springframework.graphql.data.pagination.ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor$ConnectionDataFetcher.adaptDataFetcherResult(ConnectionFieldTypeVisitor.java:219)

Since the ConnectionAdapter for the Window class is already provided, and I return a Window, I can't understand what is happening...
I add the code of the User class:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@SchemaMapping
public class User extends X implements OAuthUser, Y, Persistable<UUID> {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private UUID tenantId;

    private String tenantName;

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

...

}

I followed a tutorial video on youtube, and the only difference I see is that my application is reactive. But maybe I'm missing something other.

Why the @SchemaMapping annotation on the User domain type?

@BrianClozel I'm using GraphQL too

this shouldn't be needed
